# Introduce Ctrl + Arrow to reply to messages in chat

Tags: feature-request, chat, keyboard-shortcuts

Currently, `Ctrl + ↑ / ↓` has the same effect as `↑ / ↓`, it edits messages.

It would be nice, if `Ctrl + ↑ / ↓` could be changed to quick-respond to other messages instead. This avoids having to switch from keyboard to mouse everytime one wants to respond to a specific message.

Comment: `Ctrl + arrow` is usually preset on OS X. Rather use `Alt + arrow`.

Comment: `Ctrl` is rather standard for such actions, but `Alt` could be introduced additionally.